# How to sum multiple currencies in the same column

Tags: excel, vba

Hello and thank you all for your time, I know that I should try something before bothering you all, but I don't even know where to begin.

I need VBA code to sum up column `O` based on the currencies in column `L` and then do the same to column `P`. Finally, it should insert the values in the little table in column `S`.  It should return zero if that particular currency is not available.

Any help in any direction would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Note that columns O and P does not have an end, sometimes they are 2000+ rows long sometimes they are 4000+ rows long.

Comment: Welcome to stackowerflow! Please read how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and insert some code

Comment: I really don't know anything about coding, even if someone can show me a SUMIF formula that I can use, I would be happy. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @MohdReza you could use a simple pivot table to get what you are looking for, and if you need the format of your table, after doing the pivot table you can use the `GETPIVOTDATA` function. Pivot Table will do for you the sum of each currency, you should put currencies as rows and stock and lpo as values.

Comment: This question is too broad, and does not provide enough information to hep anyone provide an answer. How many currencies are in column L. How are the values in column O configured, are the cells formatted as currency? Please give examples of data showing each column.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, There are only four currencies. All columns, including O and P are just formatted as GENERAL, when I download the file from the server, the numbers are just there. Only the little side table on the right is formatted as currencies. Even a SUMIF function example would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could edit & use the below formulas:

**KWD**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($L$2:$L$26="KD")*($O$2:$O$26))
=SUMPRODUCT(($L$2:$L$26="KD")*($P$2:$P$26))
=SUM(T6:T7)
```

**US**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($L$2:$L$26="$")*($O$2:$O$26))
=SUMPRODUCT(($L$2:$L$26="$")*($P$2:$P$26))
=SUM(U6:U7)
```

**Results:**

[image]

**How to change range:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you SOOO much for this it works perfectly, except that I need to make it the WHOLE column, not just from 2 to 26, there are usually around 2000 to 3000 rows, based on the sale. Can we add the whole column as range? or something like this:     =SUMPRODUCT(($L$2:$L$5000="KD")*($O$2:$O$5000))

Comment: The issue is that I'm downloading this file from the server each day and need to automate some functions, but I do not know how many rows it will be, can't I choose the entire row? anyhow they are never more than 3000 rows, so just to be on the safe side I modified your formula to read from cell 26 to 5000. Thank you again so much for this.

Comment: Glad to hear that i help. if the above answer helps, vote for it.